# Single access token across different applications

Tags: android, single-sign-on

I have an Auth service which can be used in multiple apps on Android. These apps will be published by different developers but all use the same Auth service.

If a user login into one of the apps, is it possible to reuse the access token in another application?

PS: I have seen many questions and partial answers around Content Provider and Shared Prefs but there is no complete solution provided.